# Outputstream between threads

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, servlets

I have an ajax method on my servlet that could be running at the same time for the same user. Sorry if I use the wrong words to describe the problem but it's how I understand it so far (don't know much about threading).

Anyways here's the method

```
private void ajaxPartidas() throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Variables necesarias
    DataSource pool = (DataSource) session.get().getAttribute("pool");
    Recibo registro = null;

    int id = -1; 
    try{ id = Integer.parseInt(request.get().getParameter("id"));}catch(NumberFormatException e){}

    if(id > 0){
        registro = new Recibo(id);
        if(!registro.obtener(pool))
            registro = null;
        registro.setPartidas(Partida.obtenerRegistros(pool, registro.getId()));
    }

    response.get().setContentType("application/json");
    response.get().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");        
    response.get().getWriter().print((new Gson()).toJson(registro.getPartidas()));
}
```

This method is being called via ajax, it works fine the 1st time it gets called, but second time (on same id) and it returns a NullPointer on the getWriter() line. I've looked around and everyone seems to pinpoint the problem to threads. Now a little bit more of context would be that everytime the servlet enters in the

```
doPost(request, response)
```

I assign a threadlocal variable declared like so in the global vars

```
private static ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse> response = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

and I assign it the response

```
Home.response.set(response);
```

in the doPost() method.

How would I go about making the getWriter() threadsafe?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're assigning the response to a class level `ThreadLocal`? Each new user generated request has a clean `request` and `response` object. `getWriter` and all methods on the servlet class are threadsafe as long as you follow the correct guidelines for using a Java Servlet. A general rule with Java Servlets is that as long as you don't use class level variables, you are thread-safe.

Instead of using a `ThreadLocal`, you need to pass the request and response objects as parameters to your `ajaxPartidas` method and then call it as you normally would. So your `doPost` method would look like this

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ajaxPartidas(request, response);

}
```

The concurrency issues are already handled by the Servlet class itself, you just need to write the business logic. See this answer in a similar thread for more details on using a Java Servlet with Ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/772385

Comment: I do use class level variables, and used to have a problem with it (it had a message from another request, don't really know if that's the real root of that problem), but I guess I should research more about when to use threadlocal (maybe I don't need them).

Comment: In this scenario I think you wouldn't need it. The servlet API was designed to keep you from having to do your own sync/thread control unless you have a pretty strange scenario

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat creates a new Request and Response for EVERY user request. So they are already threadsafe (unless you go in and create a new Thread). Besides, make sure you are passing "id" and is getting set properly. I think it's the "registro" object on the same line as getWriter() that's causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has the id and "registro" is not null because it works on 1st attempt, then throws a NullPointerException 2nd time around.